# Nullable return type in oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, plsqldeveloper

Is it possible to return null from an oracle function?

I have the following oracle function:

```
create or replace function vta.GetAmount(p_month NUMBER)
  return number is
  v_amount number(9);
begin
  select amount
    into v_amount
    from salary
   where salary.month = p_month;
  return v_amount;
end GetAmount;
```

When the select statement returns zero rows, it raises the following exception:
`ora-01403: no data found`.

In this case I would like that the function returns null.

Comment: Your select statement is returning more than 1 row for which the code is failing, not because it is returning 0 rows. If it would have returned 0 rows, you would have got null as return.

Comment: No, if it had returned 0 rows, then you would get the no_data_found exception.

Comment: try running just this,

select amount
    from salary
   where salary.month = <user value> :

and see the results;

Comment: @Rene now the post is fine, else the earlier error points to what i was telling in my initial comment

Comment: Sorry, after retesting in PL/SQL Developer the `ORA-01403: no data found` exception is thrown. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create or replace function vta.GetAmount(p_month NUMBER)
  return number is
  v_amount number(9);
begin
  select amount
    into v_amount
    from salary
   where salary.month = p_month;
  return v_amount;
  exception   -- code to handle no data
  when no_data_found then
  return null;
  end GetAmount;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do a non-bulk implicit cursor in PL/SQL (which is what you've done with your `SELECT ... INTO ...`), you have to remember that it expects at least 1 row and at most 1 row.

If you get less than or more than 1 row, you will get an exception - either NO_DATA_FOUND or TOO_MANY_ROWS, both of which are pretty self-explanatory.

If you want the code to do something if either exception occurs, then you will need to handle those exceptions.

Eg:

```
create or replace function vta.GetAmount(p_month NUMBER)
  return number is
  v_amount number(9);
begin
  select amount
    into v_amount
    from salary
   where salary.month = p_month;
  return v_amount;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return null;
  when too_many_rows then
    return null;
end GetAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly know/want to return always one row, you could change your  select to `select nvl(sum(amount),0)`

1. `sum` makes sure you always get 1 row, because you're not grouping
2. `nvl` replaces `null` with `0` if nothing is found

Be aware that you'll get a sum of all matching rows if there are more than one, of course.